# How to add a verified publisher in a Visual Studio Installer Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin, vsinstaller

While running the msi generated by the VS Installer project that I have created, i sometimes get unknown publisher popup. But I have defined the Manufacturer and ManufacturerURL in the properties. What else do I need to do in order to mitigate the unknown publisher popup?

Answer (score 3):

You need to sign the MSI file with a valid and trusted (on the machine where the installer runs) certificate.

Comment: How do you do that? Can you share the steps.

Comment: Project Properties | Signing

Comment: Ok so this is the signing that happens for the project that you want to package into an msi file. No signing needed for the setup project in other words?

Comment: NO, .vsto file is also signed by that certificate - you can open it in Notepad.